# Deadlock in function which has a channel parameter

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Given the following simple Go program:

```
ch := make(chan int)
go fmt.Println(<- ch)
ch <- 2
```

If I replace `go fmt.Println(<- ch)` with `go func(){fmt.Println(<-ch)}()`, it works well.

But with the original version I get:

`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As defined in the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements):

> The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the calling goroutine, but unlike with a regular call, program execution does not wait for the invoked function to complete. Instead, the function begins executing independently in a new goroutine. When the function terminates, its goroutine also terminates. If the function has any return values, they are discarded when the function completes.

So the `<-ch` is evaluated. But it cannot since the channel is empty, hence it blocks until something writes to it. But there is nothing writes to it ever, hence it's a deadlock.

When you wrap it in an anonymous function - the same happens, but for the anonymous function. And then its body is evaluated concurrently to the main goroutine.

Comment: When <-ch is evaluated in main goroutine ,hence it blocks until something writes to it.But there is nothing will writes to it because main goroutine is blocked; is this understand right？@zerkms